# How to calculate the KL divergence for two multivariate pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, scipy, convergence, multivariate-distribution

I am training a Gaussian-Process model iteratively. In each iteration, a new sample is added to the training dataset (Pandas DataFrame), and the model is re-trained and evaluated. Each row of the dataset comprises 5 independent variables + the dependent variable. The training ends after 150 iterations (150 samples), but I want to extend this behaviour so the training can automatically stop after a number of iterations for which no meaningful information is added to the model.

My first approach is to compare the distribution of the last 10 samples to the previous 10. If the distributions are very similar, I assume that not meaningful knowledge has been added in the last 10 iterations, so I abort the training.

I thought of using Kullback-Leibler divergence, but I am not sure if this can be used for multivariate distributions. Should I use it? If so, how?

Additionally, is there any other better/smarter way to proceed?

Thanks